# Как разработать макет сайта без шаблонов Joomla?

Tags: php, html, css, modx, joomla

Делаю курсовую работу по теме "Разработка сайта". Одни из требований к сайту следующие:

- Наличие архива с файлами веб-страниц в формате *.html, *.css, *.js, *.php
- Наличие проекта структуры сайта
- CRM Joomla
- Разработка макета сайта без использования стандартных шаблонов Joomla
- Сайт должен корректно работать как на ПК, так и на мобильных устройствах.
- Установлено 3 доп. компонента (как приложения для MODx)

Я накатил Joomla 4.40 на Open Server и дальше встал в ступор. Шаблоны использовать нельзя, как самому создать макет сайта по собственному проекту? Я умею писать на html и css. Не проблема, сверстаю. Но как мне это все накатить на Joomla, чтобы работало? Потому что раньше я никогда не верстал шаблоны именно под Joomla или MODx, при работе с CRM нет необходимости. Я пошел за помощью к преподавателю, мне дали следующие подсказки:

- Сайт разработать на MODx Revolution (не очень понял зачем две CRM, но понял, что можно саму структуру запилить в MODx, но как на эту структуру посадить Joomla?)
- Разработать собственный шаблон можно на HTML, CSS (логично, не правда ли? Но остается открытым вопрос, какой должен быть этот шаблон, чтобы он работал на Joomla? Где взять эти стандарты, чтобы я по ним писал шаблон?)
- Создать базу данных можно в PhpMyAdmin, которую Joomla потом при ее установке заполнит автоматически (тут вообще н***я не понял, база данных как структура сайта от MODx? Что, PHP? Для чего? Зачем? Как ставить, куда пихать эту базу данных)

Короче в голове образовалась полная каша, как все это совместить, с чего начинать. Зачем база данных со структурой сайта. Я не очень в бэкэнд. Но нужно и самому хочется разобраться.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении двигаться, не нашел никаких видеоуроков на эту тему. Я могу научиться работать с MODx, сверстать как-нибудь сайт как умею +.js. Могу создать БД, в запросы и прочее могу. Но как это все в бэкэнде связать а главное ЗАЧЕМ, я не понимаю

Comment: `Шаблоны использовать нельзя` в качестве ответа, да, нельзя. но для себя как пример того что должно получиться - можно и даже нужно. `как самому создать макет сайта по собственному проекту?` для начала установи её по readme, пощупай стандартные шаблоны. а уже после, создаешь свой и переписываешь туда с стандартных то что понравилось, но не под копирку разумеется. понравилась шапка с первого шаблона? её переписываешь, футер с последнего? тоже копируешь. когда получившегося франкенштейна доведешь до состояния "оно хоть как то работает", переписываешь в чистовик. ну как то так...

Comment: Ну во-первых, не CRM Joomla, а CMS Joomla (Content Management Systems) - CRM это вооообще другое дело :)   во-вторых, видео уроков для новичков полно, как пример - https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=OyTYmctSf_E